# TemplateRef is not being initialized

Tags: javascript, angular

I have two components that I am working on, `bu-breadcrumbs` and `bu-menu`.

In `bu-breadcrumbs`, I have the breadcrumbs being created as:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'bu-breadcrumbs',
  template: `
    <nav class="breadcrumb"
    [ngClass]="{
      'is-centered': alignment === 'centered',
      'is-right': alignment === 'right',
      'has-arrow-separator': separator === 'arrow',
      'has-bullet-separator': separator === 'bullet',
      'has-dot-separator': separator === 'dot',
      'has-succeeds-separator': separator === 'succeeds',
      'is-small': size === 'small',
      'is-medium': size === 'medium',
      'is-large': size === 'large'
    }"
    [attr.aria-label]="ariaLabel">
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let breadcrumb of breadcrumbs; let idx = index"
          [ngClass]="{ 'is-active': idx === breadcrumbs.length - 1 }">
          <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="breadcrumb.templateRef"></ng-container>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  `
})
export class BulmaBreadcrumbsComponent {
  @Input('label') ariaLabel = '';
  @Input('alignment') alignment = '';
  @Input('separator') separator = '';
  @Input('size') size = '';

  @ContentChildren(BulmaBreadcrumbComponent) breadcrumbs!: QueryList<BulmaBreadcrumbComponent>;

  constructor() {}
}

@Component({
  selector: 'bu-breadcrumb',
  template: `
    <ng-template>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </ng-template>
  `
})
export class BulmaBreadcrumbComponent implements AfterContentInit {
  @ViewChild(TemplateRef) templateRef!: TemplateRef<any>;

  constructor(private readonly cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  public ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

This creates the component as I expect it should:
[image: Breadcrumb expected]

Now I'm trying to use the same technique to implement my `bu-menu` component, but the template is not being created correctly. The code currently is:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'bu-menu-list-item',
  template: `
    <ng-template>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </ng-template>
  `
})
export class BulmaMenuListItemComponent implements AfterContentInit {
  @ViewChild(TemplateRef) public templateRef!: TemplateRef<any>;

  constructor(private readonly cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    console.log('constructed')
  }

  public ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'bu-menu-list',
  template: `
    <ul class="menu-list">
      <li *ngFor="let menuItem of menuItems; let idx = index">
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="menuItem.templateRef"></ng-container>
      </li>
    </ul>
  `,
})
export class BulmaMenuListComponent {
  @ContentChildren(BulmaMenuListItemComponent) public menuItems!: QueryList<BulmaMenuListItemComponent>;

  constructor() {}
}
```

```html
<bu-menu>
  <bu-menu-label>General</bu-menu-label>
  <bu-menu-list>
    <a>Dashboard</a>
    <a>Customers</a>
  </bu-menu-list>
  <bu-menu-label>Administration</bu-menu-label>
  <bu-menu-list>
    <a>Team Settings</a>
    <a class="is-active">Manage Your Team</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a>Members</a></li>
      <li><a>Plugins</a></li>
      <li><a>Add a member</a></li>
    </ul>
    <a>Invitations</a>
    <a>Cloud Storage Environment Settings</a>
    <a>Authentication</a>
  </bu-menu-list>
  <bu-menu-label>Transactions</bu-menu-label>
  <bu-menu-list>
    <a>Payments</a>
    <a>Transfers</a>
    <a>Balance</a>
  </bu-menu-list>
</bu-menu>
```

My expectation is that the `bu-menu` should create a menu that looks like:

[image: Bulma menu expected]

But my current code doesn't seem to be loading the template correctly to repeat the `<li>` elements:

[image: Bulma menu current]

I'm stumped as to where I'm messing up in the implementation of the (I would say) same concept for this component.

Comment: Could you please create a https://stackblitz.com/ example

Comment: Your selector name is bu-menu-list-item and you are usin bu-menu @JosephQuinn

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lwr8ds?file=src/app/menu/menu.component.ts

Comment: @GaurangDhorda that doesn't explain why it works in the breadcrumbs component and not in the menu component.